# How to make the value that goes to 0, to make it to go back to same value in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python PIL module to draw some lines and I use for loop to change the width of the line. But now I would like to do, when line width is to `0`, I want to go and add value of `lw`. Basicly when width value go to zero, then I want it to go back to the 120.

This is my code...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (2000, 2000), (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

lw = 0
for y in range(-100, 2100, 100):
    lw = lw + 10
    draw.line((2000, y, 0, y), (255,0,0), 120-lw)   
img
```

This is an image from this code...

[image]

I was thinking to use `if` statement but I don't know where to incorporate it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for y in range(-100, 2100, 100):
    lw = lw + 10
    draw.line((2000, y, 0, y), (255,0,0), 120-lw)
```

Nice attempt.

---

> *I was thinking to use `if` statement but I don't know where to incorporate it. Any ideas?*

In this case I would suggest to do this:

```
for y in range(-100, 2100, 100):
    lw = lw + 10
    if (lw >= 120): # When lw reaches 120...
        lw = 0 # ...you set it to 0
    draw.line((2000, y, 0, y), (255,0,0), 120-lw)
```

---

Anyway a more elegant solution (which doesn't involve `if` statements) would be this:

```
for y in range(-100, 2100, 100):
    lw = lw + 10
    draw.line((2000, y, 0, y), (255,0,0), 120-(lw%120))
```

The `%` operator gets the remainder of `lw/120`, so that when `lw>=120` you won't have a value greater than `120` anyway.

## EDIT

---

> *I want to go from 120 to 0, and from 0 to 120. In this way it goes like this (120, 110,..., 20, 10, 0, 120, 110,...), but I would like to go like this (120, 110,..., 20, 10, 0, 10, 20,...,*

In this case you **have** to use an `if` statement:

```
incrementing = True
lw = 0
for y in range(-100, 2100, 100):
    if (lw == 120):
        incrementing = False
    elif (lw == 0):
        incrementing = True
    if (incrementing):
        lw = lw + 10
    else:
        lw = lw - 10
    draw.line((2000, y, 0, y), (255,0,0), 120-lw)
```

My suggestion is to use a `bool`ean variable to make the incrementing/decrementing easier.

Comment: Nice! But this is not quite what I want. I want to go from 120 to 0, and from 0 to 120. In this way it goes like this (120, 110,..., 20, 10, 0, 120, 110,...), but I would like to go like this (120, 110,..., 20, 10, 0, 10, 20,..., 120). Sorry if I have not explained well in a question.

Comment: Oh, no problem, I'll update my answer.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much!